# Where are the pitest statistics stored in an XML output

Tags: java, maven, pitest

I am trying to store and externally use the statistics (Line Coverage, Mutation Coverage and Test Strength) for each class, package and the overall codebase. Normally, they are contained within the HTML output but I am currently using the XML output option. Are these statistics stored anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate a file called linecoverage.xml that contains coverage statistics, whilst using both HTML **AND** XML outputs, simply add

```
<exportLineCoverage>true</exportLineCoverage>
```

to the pom.xml file as a child of the  tag.

Answer (score 1):

The statistics are currently only generated in the html output.